# Extract XML data from Hive Table and Parse the data

Tags: mysql, xml, hadoop, hive

I want to extract particular column values from a  hive table. That column has XML data.  How to parse through XML data and extract name and values from that particular XML column. Also I want to insert the extracted data into another Hive table.

Comment: XpathUDF/serde is suitable for you. pls check my answer.

Comment: was my answer useful? If yes please flag-up "accepted by owner'"

Answer (score 1):

- Option 1 : [LanguageManual XPathUDF](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+XPathUDF)

Example :

```
select xpath ('<a><b id="1"><c/></b><b id="2"><c/></b></a>','/descendant::c/ancestor::b/@id') from t1 limit 1 ;
[1","2]
```

- Option2 : Another way of achieving this is [Hive-XML-SerDe](https://github.com/dvasilen/Hive-XML-SerDe/wiki/XML-data-sources)

In both option you need to have Xpath expression knowledge.

If you want to insert extracted data in to another table then use create table as select xxx from xxxxx ([Create Table As Select (CTAS)](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableAsSelect(CTAS)))